# How Display XLSX Files in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview, xlsx

I have a xlsx file in my android assets folder. I need to display the xlsx in android. How to load and display xlsx from local assets folder.

Approach tried so far using webview:

```
val excelFilePath = "file:///android_asset/asmls.xlsx"

loadUrl(excelFilePath)
```

When I went through multiple sites, It is mentioned that xlsx is not directly supported by Android Webview. Is there any work around or alternative libraries available for the same purpose?

Comment: Why in a WebView? WebView cannot display such documents. Please change the subject of your post if you know that WebView cannot be used.

Comment: You need to parse the XLSX file.  Look at https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/index.html. This is a pure java solution to read spreadsheets into an object model, but doing this all inside a mobile app maybe unwise.  Spreadsheets can be very very large.  Then the next problem you'll have is how to render this in a likely small screen size and/or with many cells

Comment: I would question why put a xlsx file in your app. If it is just static (read only) content then convert the xlsx to csv outside of Android Studio and follow [How can I read and show data from a csv file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58225542/295004) or other similar posts. It is not clear what you expect the end-user to do with the excel file, i.e. run calculations like a full spreadsheet program, show data in a specific format or what.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding direct display of XLSX files within your app is advisable for compatibility and performance reasons. Opt for a smoother user experience by utilizing an intent chooser with the appropriate MIME type. This enables users to seamlessly open the file using their preferred external app.

```
val file = "file:///android_asset/asmls.xlsx"
val uri = Uri.parse(file)

val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")

try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an app to open the XLSX file"))
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    //handle no apps found eg inform the user
}
```

Double check the MIME type and it could be that you need to set `android:usesCleartextTraffic` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Intents to Launch External Apps by prompting the user to choose a suitable app:

> Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
> Blockquote
> intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:////path/to/your/file.xlsx"),
> "application/vnd.ms-excel");
> startActivity(intent);

2. You can use below lib ->

> implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.5")
>
> ```
> FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("file:////path/to/your/file.xlsx");
> Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);
> Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0); // Access the first sheet
>
> // Iterate through rows and cells:
> for (Row row : sheet) {
>     for (Cell cell : row) {
>         // Process cell data based on cell type (string, numeric, etc.)
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> workbook.close();